# So how do I change the text of a cell from a another function instead of cell for row at function?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I want to know if you could change the text of a cell from an another function other than in cellforrow at. Is that possible?
For ex :

```
func changeTextOfCell()
{
   // In here I want to be able to change the text of a uitableview cell. I have already created a cell in cellforrowat
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible if you simultaneously update the model. But the better approach is to modify the model and reload the row.

Comment: You don't have to do this, but can you make a simple project and show me how you would do it? The project could be very simple. Please and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

changing the cell directly is not recommended
for example if you have a model that is associated with your cell

```
class Student {

var name = String()
var age = Int()

init (name:String,age:Int) {
self.name = name
self.age = age
```

}

you can simply change the data in the model than call this to update the tableView

```
tableView.reloadData()
```